# renaming a huge folder: is it risky?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mv

Is it risky to rename folder with 180GB with the `mv` command?

We have a folder `/data` that contain 180GB.

We want to rename the `/data` folder to `/BD_FILES` with the `mv` command.

Is it safe to do that?

Comment: Why and how should it be risky? If you're unsure, call `mv` with the `-i` option.

Comment: Is there anything in your environment that leads you to think that it might be risky?

Comment: Do you mean whether there's a risk that the act in and of itself could cause a problem, or whether there's a risk that there could be problematic effects? If you have any programs that are expecting there to be a /data folder, then renaming it could cause problems.

Comment: Side-note: Almost everything is safe if you have verified backups. Nothing is as safe as it should be if you don't. In other words: when asking "is it safe", your first thought should be "have I verified my backups?"

Comment: I mean risk that could be problematic when moving huge folder with data by this OS could stop the moving in the middle for example or loose data

Comment: @yael Computers almost always work in a different way than you think.

Comment: Except when they work like you think :-) `mv` usually does atomic rename but sometimes copies, and it's a very good question to understand when (and what are the risks in copy mode).  @yael It's good to edit such clarifications into the question.

Comment: If using a linux-style file system, like `ext3`, you're fine. If however, you're dealing with an `ntfs` (or `fat`?) filesystem, you should wait for each file to be updated.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Changing the name on a folder is safe, if it stays within the same file system.

---

If it is a *mount point* (`/data` kinda looks like it could be a mount point to me, check this with `mount`), then you need to do something other than just a simple `mv` since `mv /data /BD_FILES` would move the data to the root partition (which may not be what you want to happen).

You should unmount the filesystem, rename the now empty directory, update `/etc/fstab` with the new location for this filesystem, and then remount the filesystem at the renamed location.

In other words,

1. `umount /data`
2. `mv /data /BD_FILES` (assuming `/BD_FILES` doesn't already exist, in that case, move it out of the way first)
3. update `/etc/fstab`, changing the mount point from `/data` to `/BD_FILES`
4. `mount /BD_FILES`

This does not involve copying any files around, it just changes the name of the directory that acts as the mount point for the filesystem.

---

If the renaming of the directory involves moving it to a new file system (which would be the case if `/data` is on one disk while `/BD_FILES` is on another disk, a common thing to do if you're moving things to a bigger partition, for example), I'd recommend copying the data while leaving the original intact until you can check that the copy is ok. You may do this with

```
rsync -a /data/ /BD_FILES/
```

for example, but see the `rsync` manual for what this does and does not do (it does not preserve hard links, for example).

---

Once the folder is renamed, you also need to make sure that existing procedures (programs and users using the folder, backups etc.) are aware of the name change.

Comment: There is the risk that one expects `mv` to just do a `rename` system call, but due to circumstances one hasn't realized it is going to copy the files and delete the original. If I need to be absolutely certain just a `rename` system call is made and `mv` isn't going to do something "clever" behind my back I open a Python shell and use `os.rename`.

Comment: With a relatively recent Linux kernel you can move the mount point instead: `mkdir /BD_FILES && mount -M /data /BD_FILES && rmdir /data`

Comment: I normally use `cp -r --preserve=all` rather than `rsync`.

Comment: @MichealJohnson That'll probably work on a Linux system, yes. The neat thing with `rsync` is that it's restartable.

Comment: @Kusalananda I actually know nothing about using `rsync` and am more comfortable using the same commands that I use every day and am familiar with than to risk making a mess by using an unfamiliar command. Of course if a particular user is comfortable with using `rsync` then I don't see any reason why they shouldn't, although I cannot comment on the accuracy of `rsync -a` and whether or not it preserves metadata (as is the case with `cp --preserve=all`).

Comment: @MichealJohnson One uses the tools that one is most comfortable using, obviously. Yes, `rsync -a` preserves almost all metadata, but not hard links, ACLs or extended attributes (add `-HAX` for that).

Comment: @Kusalananda tbh I don't know if `cp --preserve=all` preserves ACLs or extended attributes. I've never really needed to care about those.

Comment: @kasperd does the `rename` command work in that situation? `rename data BD_FILES /data`

Comment: @Max Different distributions have different `rename` commands with different behavior. I think that is reason enough to not use the `rename` command when you want to be certain what it is going to do.

Comment: @Max, `mv` and `cp -a` would try to preserve as much as possible including hardlinks, attributes, ACLs, sparseness... with more or less success depending on the system (`-a` is not a standard option). GNU `mv`/`cp` even recreates Unix-domain sockets (a bit pointless as it will not be magically reattached to the process(es) that are listening on it). `rsync -aHAXS` would be close, but not as efficient as GNU `cp -a` on Linux to copy sparse files.

Comment: @kasperd I just don't get why you would trust Python's `os.rename` but not coreutils' `rename`. On Linux, at least, the source for rename is tiny and is just a bunch of safety wrappers around a `rename` syscall.

Comment: @Max `rename` (either version of it) is not part of GNU coreutils. This is not the place to discuss benefits of one tool vs. another.

Comment: @Max I know of two different `rename` commands on Linux. And each of them is more complicated than just a wrapper around the `rename` system call.

Answer (score 17):

You aren't renaming every file in the directory, you're renaming **one** file in /.  That's because:

1. directories are files, and
2. the file system really cares about the inode, not the actual text.

Thus, renaming a directory, no matter how many files or how much data is in it, is trivial.

Answer (score 14):

If you just rename (source and target in *same* file system), it is simply a rename of a directory entry. It either succeeds and the directory has new name, or fails in which case nothing changes <sup>*</sup>.

If the source and target are on different file systems the data needs to be copied by `mv`. Differences in file system features, such as maximum file size, limitations in file names, etc., can cause problems. To avoid issues, first copy files (`cp`, `rsync`, …) and after copy completes successfully, remove the files in the original location.

<sub>* However there are some corner cases, for example mentioned in the *BUGS* section in [*man 2 rename*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man2/rename.2.html#contenttoc8)</sub>

Comment: >"It either succeeds and the directory has new name, or fails in which case nothing changes". How it's guaranteed? Is it true for all filesystems? Are there any documentation about this?

Comment: Rename is a single syscall, however there is a note about NFS in *BUGS* section of [*man rename*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man2/rename.2.html#contenttoc8): rename can be successful even when error is returned when using NFS (see details in the man page). I added a note in the answer too. I don't expect any file system in kernel to consider it acceptable for a directory entry vanish should a rename fail.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, renaming a folder poses no inherent risk to the contents. 
But there is a different kind of risk you may want to consider.

Existing procedures, scripts, user-defined shortcuts, and configurations which reference the original location could be broken by this change, and if the paths are stored in a database, for example, updating them could be a big job.

One thing you can do is make a symbolic link for the new directory name, but leave the old name in place for a while. That will give you time to evaluate the impact of this change. You could temporarily remove the old name, see if there are any problems, and if there are, just recreate the old name so people can continue working while you figure out what needs to be updated.

A command something like this should do it :
   `ln -s /data /BD_FILES`

Comment: One more mild risk that no-one has mentioned yet, is that depending on your backup strategy for that folder, it might lead to disk space and latency issues on the backup drive due to 180GB of "new" data suddenly appearing, and needing to be backed up.

Comment: I prefer something like `mv thing1 thing2 ; ln --symbolic ./thing2 thing1`.  That way I've got the new name and can easily test absence of the old by deleting the symlink.

Answer (score 3):

Rename is atomic. The only reasonable risk is that `mv` decides to copy everything for some reason and that crashes half way through. If you have GNU `mv`, `mv -T` will remove this risk.

`mv -T` tells `mv` that it's moving to a non-folder; which will cause it to refuse to do `mkdir()` which in turn will cause it to fail if moving a folder and it decided to copy for some reason.

I was involved in shaking bugs out of `mv -T` while working on my master's thesis years ago. It used to do the wrong thing on too many edge cases.

On the other hand, you have 180GB of user data on the root partition. You probably do want to move this off the root partition.

Comment: You can't possibly tell from the name alone if something is in the "root partition" or not.

Comment: @Peter: If it's not on the root partition it's a mountpoint. You can't rename mounted mountpoints with the mv command.