# How to safely move a directory to a different partition?

Tags: files, filesystems

My `/` partition keeps filling up. To mitigate this, I'd like to move `/opt` to a different directory, `/usr/local/foo`, which is mounted to a different partition.

How do I do this safely? If I simply move `/opt` to `/usr/local/foo/opt` then create a link of some sort from `/opt --> /usr/local/foo/opt`, will all the permissions, bits, etc. be correctly set up?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: [renaming a huge folder: is it risky?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394169)

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -a
```

followed by

```
mount --bind --make-slave
```

Comment: Your answer is good for the most part, rsync and mount --bind are great here, but can you complement it to cover the OP's use case? What rsync command would be appropriate? How to empty /opt before mounting on top of it? How to get the bind mount to get mounted automatically on boot? (What syntax should be used in /etc/fstab for that?)